# Can I access the content as a string from React Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component like this

```
import React, { useContext } from 'React'
import Context from "./Context"

function foo(props){
  const aContext = useContext(Context);
  const { region } = aContext;
  const { code } = props;
  const bar = {a: 'abc', b:'qwe'};

  return <div> {region} {bar[code]} </div>
}

export default foo
```

I want to access `{bar[code]}` content as a string from another component, how can I achieve it?

EDIT: Edit the code

Comment: Why, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Move it to the parent component and pass as property or create a contextt and access the content down the tree with a provider

Comment: I am sorry that I did not describe my question clearly. The text content will change based on the props variable provided, however, if I use as a React Component, it becomes an object, I would like it to be a string. Also, I am also using the useContext hooks in the compoent, so it has to be a React Component rather than a pure JS function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to update the parent component or the context by passing a callback as a prop, then calling it whenever you want the parent to be updated.

Lets say you have this code somewhere in the parent component returned value (render):

```
.
.
<sibling />
<foo /> 
.
.
```

Then you can create a function that updates the state of this parent component using `useState`, and pass the state to the `sibling`. In addition, pass the updating function to `foo` and call it inside `foo`:

```
.
.
const [text, setText] = useState('');
.
.
//return(...
.
<sibling text={text} />
<foo setText={setText} code={'a'} /> 
.
.
```

Now in `foo`:

```
import React from 'React'

function foo(props){
  const { code } = props
  const bar = {a: 'abc', b:'qwe'}

  props.setText(bar[code]);

  return <div> {bar[code]} </div>
}

export default foo
```